# Creating repositories under Ubuntu Landscape

Tags: landscape

I am just getting started with using Ubuntu Landscape. The plan is to use the quickstart version to gain experience with managing Ubuntu servers, 16 and 18, and to also create an on-site repository to limit traffic over the Internet from each asset.

We are currently using Landscape On Premise release 19.01.

I am going to list the steps I believe are to be correct for our Ubuntu 18, bionic, servers.

landscape-api create-distribution ubuntu

landscape-api create-series --pockets release,security,updates --components main,extras,restricted --architectures i386,amd64 --gpg-key secret-key --mirror-uri http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ --mirror-series bionic bionic ubuntu

landscape-api sync-mirror-pocket release bionic ubuntu
landscape-api sync-mirror-pocket security bionic ubuntu
landscape-api sync-mirror-pocket updates bionic ubuntu

What else do I need to do after these commands? What needs to be corrected?

Very respectfully,

James

Answer (score 1):

The issue was very much related to firewall rules. It seems that onedrive was a flagged security application.

Answer (score 0):

Creating distribution, uploading a signing key, creating the series and syncing; that is pretty much it.

After that, it's a matter of waiting for the sync activity to complete, then configuring your machines to use the mirror. That can be done manually on each machine (by pointing to your Landscape server in `/etc/apt/sources.list`), or through landscape by assigning repository profiles to computers.

All of this is documented in the user guide: https://docs.ubuntu.com/landscape/en/repositories

Comment: Okay, I will start with these steps and report back my results.

Comment: Okay, my first two attempts to sync failed with the following:
Could not find 'extras/binary-i386/Packages' within './lists/update-bionic_bionic_InRelease'
There have been errors!
Could not find 'extras/binary-i386/Packages' within './lists/update-bionic-security_bionic-security_InRelease'

There have been errors!

Comment: I deleted the series and then re-added it. So far, it looks like it is going slow.

Comment: Well...It was going well until it died at 99%. Error message from Landscape:
Calculating packages to get...
Getting packages...
Got 1%: 1G 14M bytes
Got 2%: 1G 997M bytes
Got 3%: 3G 258M bytes
Got 4%: 3G 968M bytes
Got 5%: 5G 419M bytes
Got 6%: 5G 935M bytes
Got 7%: 6G 919M bytes
Got 8%: 8G 161M bytes
.
.
.
Got 48%: 47G 288M bytes
aptmethod error receiving 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/onedrive/onedrive_1.1.20170919-2ubuntu2_i386.deb':
'401  Access Denied [IP: 91.189.88.149 80]'
Got 49%: 48G 299M bytes
Got 50%: 49G 261M bytes

Comment: Continuing on
Got 86%: 84G 725M bytes
aptmethod error receiving 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/onedrive/onedrive_1.1.20170919-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb':
'401  Access Denied [IP: 91.189.88.162 80]'
Got 87%: 85G 779M bytes
.
.
.
Got 94%: 92G 609M bytes
Got 95%: 93G 660M bytes
Got 96%: 94G 598M bytes
Got 97%: 95G 556M bytes
Got 98%: 96G 540M bytes
Got 99%: 97G 524M bytes
90544 files were added but not used.
The next deleteunreferenced call will delete them.
There have been errors!

Comment: When I tried again I got the following:
Sync pocket 'release' of series 'bionic' in distribution 'ubuntu'

Calculating packages to get...
Getting packages...
aptmethod error receiving 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/onedrive/onedrive_1.1.20170919-2ubuntu2_i386.deb':
'401  Access Denied [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]'
aptmethod error receiving 'http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/o/onedrive/onedrive_1.1.20170919-2ubuntu2_amd64.deb':
'401  Access Denied [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]'
There have been errors!

Comment: Restarted, but eliminated the i386 architecture.

Comment: Nope!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
Failed AGAIN at 99%.

Is there not any singular Landscape support forum?

Comment: As of this time, 12 MAR 2-19, it seems the issue is on our end but we are at a loss as to why.

Comment: Issue resolved itself on its own. My best guess is that some firewall rules were revised.

Comment: Okay, this has been a recent issue for both the test server at work and my own home server running Landscape and I am at my witts end trying to resolve it.

I am trying to sync the repos:
 u'result_text': u"ERROR: Condition 'CB1CD4BC8644FC41' not fulfilled for './lists/update-bionic_bionic_InRelease'.\r\nSignatures in './lists/update-bionic_bionic_InRelease':\r\n'3B4FE6ACC0B21F32' (signed 2018-04-26): missing pubkey\r\nError: Not enough signatures found for remote repository update-bionic (http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic)!\r\nThere have been errors!\r\n",